# Issue with the Scalar Potential for an electric field

Tags: electrostatics, potential

I've been given a question saying to give the time-dependent Hamiltonian for the atomic electron in the E-field in the form of a scalar potential.

My question is: as scalar potential is defined $E = -\nabla V$ and the given E-field is $E = E(t) \hat{z}$, I've written my scalar potential $V(t)$ as $V(t) = E(t)z$.

However, the mark scheme denotes it as $V(t) = -qE(t)z$, and I don't know why the -q is necessary. If you could explain it, that'd be great thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to differentiate between electrostatic potential $\Phi$ and potential energy $V$ used in the Hamiltonian. Since the electric field $\vec E$ is a force per charge, the electrostatic potential must also be potential energy per charge:
$$\vec F=q\vec E$$
$$\vec F=-\vec \nabla V$$
Therefore,
$$\vec E=-\frac{1}{q}\vec \nabla V=-\vec \nabla \Phi$$
and finally
$$V=q\Phi$$
So if you have $\vec E=(0,0,E(t))$, you need $\Phi=-E(t)z$ and hence $V=-qE(t)z$.